# Rewrite f# functions with continuation-passing style

Tags: f#, functional-programming, ocaml

This question is about functional programming. The sample code is in F#.

Suppose I have a simple function f:

```
let f x = 
    x + 1
```

Now (for reasons I don't want to explain, related to threading) I must turn f into a function with continuations:

```
let f x cont =
    cont (x+1)
```

Now I must rewrite all functions that call f, which won't compile anymore.

For example, if I have this function

```
let g x =
   let res = f x
   res + 2
```

I must rewrite g as

```
let g x cont =
    f x (fun res ->
            cont (res + 2) )
```

This is becoming complicated already, but is still manaegable.

But the problem is: how do I rewrite the following piece of code?

```
let lmapped = [ for x in l do
                    let res = f x
                    yield res + 1 ]
if List.isEmpty lmapped then
   ...
```

is there a simple way to rewrite it? (Possibly avoiding an explicit recursive function, like "let rec ...") Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Writing code using explicit continuation passing style gets ugly quite quickly.

In this case, you'd need to write continuation-based version of the `List.map` function:

```
let map f list cont = 
  let rec loop acc list cont = 
    match list with
    | [] -> cont (List.rev acc) // Reverse the list at the end & call continuation!
    | x::xs -> f x (fun x' ->   // Call `f` with `cont` that recursively calls `loop`
        loop (x'::acc) xs cont )// Call `loop` with newly projected element in `acc`
  loop [] list cont
```

In principle, this is just a "simple syntactic transformation" that can be done "automatically", but it is very hard to do this without getting lost!

The function is really just an ordinary `map` function with inner `loop` function that recursively iterates over the input list and calls `f` to do the projection. Except that all the functions take additional parameter `cont` and return result by calling `cont` at the end. This is also the case for the `f` function passed to map! See:

```
map (fun n cont -> cont (n * 2)) [1 .. 10] (printfn "%A")
```

If you're using continuations heavily, then it is perhaps easier to write computation builder (aka monad) for working with continuations. This does not quite fit in a single StackOverflow answer, but see this [excellent post by Brian McNamara](http://lorgonblog.wordpress.com/2008/06/07/catamorphisms-part-seven/)

Answer (score 0):

So to answer the question using Tomas' map function:

first rewrite the code as

```
let lmapped = List.map
               (fun x ->
                   let res = f x
                   res + 1 )
               l
if List.isEmpty lmapped then
  ...
```

and then we can rewrite with continuations:

```
map
   (fun x cont ->
         f x (fun res ->
                 cont (res + 1 )))
   l
   (fun lmapped ->
        if List.isEmpty lmapped then

             ... 
        )
```